# Facebook Cover Photo API using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has Facebook released any api for facebook cover photo?
I want to implement it using PHP language.

EDIT

I want to upload cover photo in facebook timeline using graph api PHP

Comment: Please be detailed (and clear) what you exactly wanted to do.

Comment: I just edited the question. I want to upload cover photo for fb timeline using graph api php

Comment: @Kamini : what you have done so far??

Comment: I have no clue for this app. I know how to upload photo to album using php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it is not possible to change the profile picture directly via Facebook Photo Graph API as no section mention about that.

However, we can do a trick by uploading user’s photo to Facebook via the API then redirect the user to uploaded photo URL with 1 added in querystring parameter as below:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=xyz&id=abc&makeprofile=1

“&makeprofile=1″ is the main thing here and xyz/abc will be returned by Facebook. By adding the parameter, Facebook will auto change the profile picture of the current user with the uploaded picture above.

For more info: 
http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/php-change-facebook-profile-picture-with-graph-api/

Comment: I want to change / add the timeline cover photo instead of profile photo.

Answer (score 8):

There is an api for updating the cover photo on a page

#### http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

It asks for a photo id which i guess is the id of a photo from the users album.

Comment: I will read the doc. Is it only for page? Or can i use it for user profiles too?

Comment: yes you may be, i havn't tested it. AFAIK facebook doesn't released cover API yet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9908/discussion-between-diecho-and-kamini)

Comment: actually graph api allows to change the cover photo of the created pages not the cover photos of users' profile pages

Answer (score 1):

You can upload photo to an album via graph api. Get the new photo id and redirect user to this url

```
 "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=" + photo_id
```

before that, you should inform the user that he/she will be redirected to facebook to page where they can  set new cover photo (they need to confirm the change, click the save button). It's not perfect solution, and not fully covered api but it's best way out there asfaik.